# Seemingly random error appearing when executing code in Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyerror

Below is a portion of code from a program I have written that is by all means pretty basic.

```
pc1 = random.choice(cards)
cca1 = random.choice(cards)
while (pc1 == cca1):
    cca1 = random.choice(cards)
ccb1 = random.choice(cards)
while (pc1 == ccb1) or (cca1 == ccb1):
    ccb1 = random.choice(cards)
```

`pc1`, `cca1` and `ccb1` are just names of variables, shortened for ease of use. What this portion of code does is try to take 3 entries from a dictionary named cards. It uses the while functions to ensure that the chosen cards are not the same; they will always be different.

This goes on until I have 9 unique variables from my dictionary of 52, and it works fine except for  sometimes producing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Programs\Poker\1.0.py", line 231, in <module>
    ccc2 = random.choice(cards)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\random.py", line 252, in choice
    return seq[i]
KeyError: 0
```

The variable in the error above (`ccc2`) is just a continuation of the previously shown code, and the variable supposedly causing the error changes every time.

The error only occurs sometimes (sometimes the program runs fine, other times it shows the error), and the line it occurred on also changes with every appearance.
I understand my code is inefficient but I'm really just looking to stop this error, and maybe some useful ideas/hints on how to improve.

Once again; does what its supposed to but unidentifiably returns the error mentioned at seemingly random times with a seemingly random site of cause.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way `random.choice` works is designed for sequences, not mappings. It picks indices, so will sometimes try `cards[0]`, which evidently isn't a valid key. The reason that the error appears random is, of course, because it depends on the value picked by `random`!

You can fix this by explicitly choosing from a sequence:

```
random.choice(list(cards))
```

To improve your code more generally, note that `random` also includes [`sample`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
rcards = random.sample(list(cards), 3) # pick three random cards
```

Note that in both cases, we randomly choose *keys* from the dictionary.

Comment: Great, thank you for the response, I have edited my code with you suggestion of .keys() and it seems to work fine now. I will also look into your recommendation for improving my code, thank you for the help!

Comment: Hey jon, thanks for your help earlier, just put your suggestions into practice and realise I forgot to mention I want to retrieve the values from the dictionary entries, not the keys! Is this possible to do and how could I do it?

Comment: Once you have the keys, get the values as you normally would: `val = cards[key]`. Alternatively, choose/sample randomly from the `cards.values()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The second option you suggested returns the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Programs\Poker\1.0.py", line 212, in <module>
    pc1 = random.choice(cards.values())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\random.py", line 252, in choice
    return seq[i]
TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing`

Comment: That's a Py2/Py3 thing, sorry: use `list(cards.values())`